# Overflow:scroll doesn't show the entire div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a fixed position sidebar, which has a small header and a scrollable div underneath.

My problem is that I cannot scroll through the entire div, so I can't see everything in it.

Here's my code and [here it is on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9V45d/1/).

HTML

```
<section>
<header>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>
</header>
<div class="scroll-box">FIRST LINE
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>doesn't matter
    <br>we have some text here
    <br>a few lines
    <br>LAST LINE
    <br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    section {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}
.scroll-box {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
.scroll-box {
   height:100%;
}
```

You can't set the `height` to 100% because yo also have a header in the section that takes space.

Distribute the total 100% to the `header` and the `.scroll-box`

```
section header{
  height:30%;
}
.scroll-box {
  overflow: auto;
  height:70%;
  background: #eee;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/9V45d/8/**

Comment: That seems to be the problem. But how can I make it responsive ? I know what's the height of the header, because it doesn't change, but I want the scroll-box to fill the rest of the screen vertically.
I know how to make it with jQuery, but I wonder if there's a CSS solution for it.

Comment: I don't think it can be posible only with CSS specially for the `overflow` ... he need a fixed height.

Comment: I'll do it with jQuery then. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the size of the div with the class scroll box to 100% of the size of the screen. There header is taking up space on the page so the scroll area is cropped.

If you change the css to:

```
.scroll-box {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 91%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
```

you will be able to see the entire scroll box and all of the values. So you need to distribute the 100% between the header and the scroll

Comment: It's just an example on JSFiddle. I'm using this on a website and I only see the same portion of the div on every resolution, so it's not caused by JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry should have explained that it is not because of jsfiddle but because of the space the header is taking up.